# Function templates and Private Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, function, inheritance, private

I recently ran into a problem when using a private inheritance scheme in which the base class defined a template method and the (privately) derived class made that method public via a using declaration under the `public` access specifier. The template was designed to take the address of a function and invoke that function pointer. However, upon attempting to pass the name of the function to the derived class template method, I receive an error message that states that the base-class method cannot access a private member declared in the derived class. Here is a code segment that models the issue:

```
class A
{ 
public:
     template<class T> void Funct(T pFunct) { }
};

class B : private A
{
public:
    using A::Funct;
};

void Show(void) { }

int main(void)
{
    B b;
    b.Funct(Show);
}
```

The exact resulting error message is: `'A::Funct' : cannot access private member declared in class 'B'`

I am able to resolve the issue simply by:

1)Preceding the function argument name with the address-of operator:

```
b.Funct(&Show);
```

2)Explicitly qualifying the template type argument:

```
b.Funct<void(*)(void)>(Show)
```

If the `Show()` function were a template as well, I would need to explicitly qualify the template using the proper template type arguments used to instantiate `Show`.

My question is not how to solve the problem but why the error message is being generated. Why does instantiating `Funct()` with `Show` versus with `&Show` cause the compiler to do two different things. And why does instantiating `Funct()` with `Show` cause the `Funct()` method to attempt to access the private data in class `B` (which I'm assuming is the `A` subobject in class `B`)?

Comment: What compiler? You example compiles fine with g++ 4.2.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Comment: Is this visual studio?  Some of the older versions had problems with member function pointers in template parameters.

Comment: Yeah, it is VC. Might be some sort of bug then?

Comment: Using Intellisense, if you don't have `&Show` or specify `void(*)(void)` as the type explicitly, VC does not know the correct type for the template.  If you have `&Show`, Intellisense will correctly display `Funct<void(*)(void)>` as the fully qualified function when you hover over it.

Answer (score 1):

Compiles fine with Comeau Online. Ergo, compiler bug. Report it.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

bcc32 gives error: `error bccE2247: 'Funct<void (*)()>(void (*)())' is not accessible in function main()`

I believe this is a compiler bug.